# Questions about multi-boot

Tags: berryboot, multiboot

Good afternoon everyone.
I installed raspbian / retropie / kodi by berryboot .
Whenever I turn , appears the OS selection screen to boot .
I would like to hold the automatically boot the last OS used .
I would also like to create a file in raspbian that clicking the system a reboot and enter the retropie and to enter the kodi .
This possibility should be back to the raspbian retropie and kodi well.
How should I proceed?